# Overwrite text in a specific div in a file (PHP HTML)

Tags: php, html, slideshow

I am creating a slideshow editor. I have been able to parse a file and present it to the user in a form. Now I need to figure out how to write the saved information to the file. I want the user to be able to edit the information before and after the slideshow, so there is no specific set of information to be able to overwrite the whole file.

If there is a way to get all of the text before the div and copy it to the variable, add the new information, then get the rest of the information after the div and add that to the variable and then write all that information to the file, then that would work. Otherwise, here is what I have put together.

```
                /* Set Variables */
    $x = $_POST['x'];
    $file = $_POST['file'];
    $path = '../../yardworks/content_pages/' . $file;
    $z=0;

    while ($z<$x){
        $title[$z] = $_POST['image-title'.$z];
        $description[$z] = $_POST['image-desc'.$z];
        $z++;
    }

    for ($y=0; $y<$x; $y++){
        $contents .= '<li>
    <a class="thumb" href="images/garages/'.$file[$y].'">
        <img src="images/garages/'.$file[$y].'" alt="'.$title[$y].'" height="100px" width="130px" class="slideshow-img" />
    </a>
    <div class="caption">
        <div class="image-title">'.$file[$y].'</div>
        <div class="image-desc">'.$description[$y].'</div>
    </div>
</li>';
    }

    /* Create string of contents */
    $mydoc = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
    $mydoc->loadHTMLFile($path);
    $mydoc->getElementById("replace")->nodeValue = $contents;
    $mydoc->saveHTMLFile($path);

    $file = file_get_contents($path);
    $file = str_replace("&lt;", "<", $file);
    $file = str_replace("&gt;", ">", $file);
    file_put_contents($path, $file);

?>
```

Nothing throws out an error, but the file also remains unchanged. Is there anything I can change or fix to make it write to the file? This is all I have been able to find regarding this specific problem.

I would like to stick to one language, but if I find a way to write to the file using javascript, do the php variables pass on to the javascript section or do I have to stick with one language?

**Edit
Everything is working. ONE problem: is there a way to keep the special characters without converting them? I need the < and > to stay as they are and not convert to a string

Comment: i'm not seeing a node with an id of replace

Comment: Have you try `print_r($contents)` and `print_r($html->getElementById('replace')->nodeValue)` ?

Comment: @Orangepill --> The ID is in the external file that I'm trying to write to. I thought I was accessing that file with `loadHTMLFile`. @furas --> if I print the contents and then replace that contents, how do I take that contents and write it to the external file?

Comment: `file_put_contents($filename, $html->getElementById('replace')->nodeValue)`

Comment: Do I replace all of the 'write to file' code with this one line?

Comment: Orangepill show you only how to write to external file. You removed `DOMDocument` so `$html` not exist and your code doesn't work.

Comment: We want to know what PHP is doing (step by step) so you can put in many places `print_r($contents)` (or even better `echo "<pre>"; print_r($contents); echo "</pre>";`) to see how `$contents` is changing. You can do the same with other variables. In this way you (and we) can see what script is doing.

Comment: I have made an edit. Can you tell me what I'm doing wrong in the `replaceChild` area?

Comment: What do you mean `< and > to stay as they are` ? Do you mean `<` and `>` in tags (ex. `<div>`) ? Maybe you need `->innerHTML` in place of `->nodeValue`.

Comment: That's what I mean. That works in theory, but it causes the file not to save. I've noticed this is a common problem, but none of the fixes I'm finding are working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have decided to save the file as it is and use a separate code set to replace the string. I have edited my question above.